# running a Python script from Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying simply to run `python --version` from Jenkins in both ways, as you see in the image

NOTE:

on the same machine that jenkins runs, if I run the same command or any other Python script, it runs with no problem but via jenkins doesn't recognize it.

[image]

and I get the following error:

```
15:16:19 C:\Project\Jenkins\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX>exit 0 
15:16:19 [TUNSDK] $ sh -xe C:\Users\XXX\jenkins3628552658524167869.sh
15:16:19 + sh python --version
15:16:19 sh: python: No such file or directory
15:16:19 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
15:16:20 Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I run a python script via jenkins

Comment: executing sh and bat in the same build? your agent in windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have python in the current dir or your full path to python is not available in the system environment. Try to add it to systems variables or place the full path for python.exe in the command line. You could find more information at: [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: Python is in my environment Path. I can run it in the same system wherever.